# Group by or Aggregate over Vectors or Lists

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

I would like to group the following data.frame by Quarter and to sum over Sample.

```
Month   Quarter   Sample
1       1         c(1, 2, ...)
2       1         c(1, 3, ...)
3       1         c(2, 1, ...)
4       2         c(0, 1, ...)
5       2         c(1, 0, ...)
6       2         c(1, 1, ...)
```

The resulting data.frame should look like

```
Quarter   Sample
1         c(4, 6, ...)
2         c(2, 2, ...)
```

Here is a sample code which creates the same data structure:

```
myData = data.frame(Month = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                    Quarter = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"))

myData$Sample <- lapply(1:6,function(x) c(x,x+1))
```

Comment: Is sample column a vector?

Comment: Im not sure about the structure here, because i think you cant have vectors in a column of a data.frame. If you have this as a matrix, you could take the sum of all vectors from Sample, where Quarter is the same

Comment: Please add data using `dput`, `dput(df)`.

Comment: Here is a sample r code which creates the same data structure:  `myData = data.frame(Month = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), Quarter = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"))
myData$Sample <- lapply(1:6,function(x) c(x,x+1)) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pmap_dbl()` to sum the values in parallel:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

myData %>%
  group_by(Quarter) %>%
  summarise(Sample = list(pmap_dbl(Sample, sum))) %>%
  as.data.frame()

  Quarter  Sample
1       1    6, 9
2       2  15, 18
```

Comment: Thanks! This one creates a list not vector for column Sample. I would prefer c(6,9) over list{6,9}.

Comment: @Mohsen - Edited.  Using `pmap_dbl()` instead of `pmap()` addresses this.

Comment: Great, it is working. You may edit the first line of your answer: "You can use pmap() to sum the values in parallel:"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this with `dplyr`, we `unnest` the data to get list columns into separate `rows`, we assign a unique number for every value in `Sample` in each row. We then `group_by` `Quarter` to get `sum` of `Sample` and get the data again in a list format.

```
library(dplyr)

out_df <- myData %>%
             tidyr::unnest(Sample) %>%
             group_by(Month) %>%
             mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
             group_by(Quarter, row) %>%
             summarise(Sample = sum(Sample)) %>%
             summarise(Sample = list(Sample)) %>% data.frame()
out_df

#  Quarter Sample
#1       1   6, 9
#2       2 15, 18
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure about the efficiency and size running unnest when the length of the vectors ( c(1,2,...) )  is large.

Comment: @Mohsen I am not sure either. Let me know what you find out.